Impact of changes from Microsoft Azure AD to Microsoft Entra ID
Microsoft Azure changed the name of Azure AD and AAD to Microsoft Entra ID in 2023 August,

Is this only name change of the products or any impacts to the product configurations and the usage anywhere int he Azure app family?
As per documentation Azure AD name only changes, but how Entra ID providing advantages as a Microsoft Entra Product family?
Entra ID separates the concepts of Active directory vs resource identity and access management (IAM)?
And as per documentation, when an org or app dev will receive enter ID when a relationship got created with Microsoft. Is this a unique ID created for org or app dev? or Microsoft Entra ID is for each available resource from Azure? and how these Entra ID's of resources are related to each other.


A tenant represents an organization. It's a dedicated instance of
Microsoft Entra ID that an organization or app developer receives at
the beginning of a relationship with Microsoft.


Microsoft Azure AD is now called Microsoft Entra ID. This change is mostly a rebrand, but it also brings new features to better manage user and resource access across Microsoft's cloud services. The core functions remain the same.

Thank you for the update @Rukmini, is Entra ID is providing unique ID for resource access management of each Azure resources or limited to few resources like organizations and app developers? and how these Entra ID's  are related to other resources and Entra product family?

AFAIK Microsoft Entra ID primarily manages identities for users and apps, while Azure resources like VMs and databases use Managed Identities for secure access to other services. It integrates with other Entra products for more advanced identity governance and access management across the cloud ecosystem


Note that: Microsoft Azure AD is now called Microsoft Entra ID. This change is mostly a rebrand, but it also brings new features to better manage user and resource access across Microsoft’s cloud services. The core functions remain the same.


Microsoft Entra ID mainly handles user and app identities, while Azure resources like virtual machines (VMs) and databases use Managed Identities to securely access other services.
It works with other Entra products to provide more advanced control over identity and access management across the cloud.

Microsoft Entra ID still includes the same features as Azure AD, such as managing users and groups, Single Sign-On (SSO), and Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA). The switch to Entra ID doesn’t affect these features.

Any existing Azure AD settings, like users, groups, and roles, will still work in Entra ID. However, users will need to learn the new terms used in the portal, documentation, and APIs.
While the core identity management features remain the same, Entra ID introduces enhanced integration with resource identity management, providing more control over user and resource access.

Microsoft Entra ID is not just for organizations and app developers; it applies to all identity and access management in Azure resources.
